# Live preview for Rmarkdown documents using Rstudio

Tags: rstudio, r-markdown

I have been using VScode as my main markdown platform for notetaking and I got really used to the live preview capabilities.

Now I have to use Rmarkdown to generate an updatable report and I would like to know if anyone knows how to generate live previews using Rstudio.

I am not happy with Vscode extensions regarding R and Rmarkdown. Visual Studio Rtools does in fact have a live preview but the IDE is a lot slower and less optimized (in my opinion) when compared to Rstudio.

Notice that i know how to knit, what i would like would be to avoid knitting everytime i need to check the document.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I would suggest that you use AsciiDoc instead.

Answer (score 6):

For HTML output you can use `xaringan::infinite_moon_reader(file)`. After this, the file will automatically be processed on saving it. From it's documentation:

> **Note**
>
> This function is not really tied to the output format
> `moon_reader()`. You can use it to serve any single-HTML-file R Markdown
> output.

Comment: Dear @Ralf thank you very much for your suggestion. I didn't know this package and although it works it doesn't had that much compared to a Rnotebook which already let's you preview after you save (and that is the solutions we will be using for the time being). Is a second best option ... i am studing if it is possible to creat an add in for a Rnotebook that would autosave every x seconds and trick Rstudio to make a live preview. Once again thank you very much.

Comment: Thanks for this, I think it may be useful to mention that it comes with a premade RStudio addin that can be mapped to a keyboard shortcut to make the use more convenient.

Comment: Does anyone know how to do live previews in Markdown with an ````output: pdf_document:````?

Answer (score 0):

A slight update: you can now seemlessly use Rstudio addins in VS Code. In fact, using this feature, the infinite moon reader works even better than in Rstudio (does never crash). I hence moved all my writing (markdown, rmd, and latex) and coding to VS Code.