# R Markdown: beamer presentation real time preview

Tags: r, r-markdown, beamer, presentation, xaringan

Is there a way to preview the result of knitting a R Markdown document into a beamer presentation?

In particular, I would like that, every time I save the file, the .Rmd document gets compiled and the slide in which I am is being displayed in the "Viewer" pane of RStudio.

[xaringan](https://github.com/yihui/xaringan) has the function `infinite_moon_reader` that achieves exactly this, but I want to output Beamer presentations and the syntax of the Beamer output is different from xaringan (in particular, in Beamer output a new slide is created by `##` while in xaringan a new slide is created by three dashes `---`)

Releated question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52646130/live-preview-for-rmarkdown-documents-using-rstudio)

Comment: This is nearly impossible, unless there is a way to programmatically navigate to a certain page of the PDF (which is possible in HTML slides, so **xaringan** could do it). The best we could possibly achieve is to click in Rmd and navigate to a page in PDF, but even implementing this would be very challenging (if I were to do it, it might take a whole month). This feature is only available to Rnw documents: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200552066